# how to reduce the time complexity of this code

Tags: arrays, ruby, time-complexity

arr1 is a array have 3 element 1st is number of element in arr2, 2nd is no of rotation 3rd is no. of input. I want to print the element of arry2 from given input index by user. 2nd input arry is input array contain array element.

```
arr1 =gets.strip.split(' ').map(&:to_i)
arr2 = gets.strip.split(' ').map(&:to_i)

q=arr1[2]
count= arr1[1]

count.times do
  arr2=arr2.reverse.rotate.reverse
end

for i in 0..q-1 do
  i = gets.strip.to_i
  puts "#{arr2[i]}\n"
end
```

Comment: Can you please add an example for `arr1` and `arr2` and the expected output?

Comment: The narrative is pretty much unreadable.  I'd fix it if I knew what it should say, but I'm afraid I don't.  Can you please edit the question for clarity, paying attention to punctuation, spelling, and so on?  I realize you are not a native English speaker, and that's OK, but I hope you can make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`rotate`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-rotate) takes an argument which is the number of elements to rotate by. This number can be negative to rotate in the other direction, so

```
count.times do
  arr2=arr2.reverse.rotate.reverse
end
```

which copies the array 3 times on each iteration, can be replaced by

```
arr2 = arr2.rotate(-count)
```